# Скачал Swift, ничего не работает, помогите!

Tags: swift

Установил Swift 5.6.1, зашёл в VSCODE и тут такое...:

```
<module-includes>:1:10: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#include "AssertionReporting.h"
         ^
C:\Library\Developer\Platforms\Windows.platform\Developer\SDKs\Windows.sdk\usr\lib\swift\shims/AssertionReporting.h:16:10: note: in file included from C:\Library\Developer\Platforms\Windows.platform\Developer\SDKs\Windows.sdk\usr\lib\swift\shims/AssertionReporting.h:16:
#include "SwiftStdint.h"
         ^
C:\Library\Developer\Platforms\Windows.platform\Developer\SDKs\Windows.sdk\usr\lib\swift\shims/SwiftStdint.h:28:10: error: 'stdint.h' file not found
#include <stdint.h>
         ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build C module 'SwiftShims'
```

Comment: Первую строку ошибки забыли скопировать. Давайте я предположу какова эта строка :) ```error: manifest parse error(s):```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Я не забыл ни какой строки, там такой нету